# Android Studio - PC crash when emulator run

Tags: android, android-studio

we have a PC with Android Studio installed, when we run emulator we have a crash of the system and need to power off the PC.

PC: DELL Precision 3580, i7-1355U, ram 16GB, onboarded graphic unit
Windows 10 PRO 22H2

Android Studio: Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2 -- Same issue with latest version iguana 2023.2.1

In Android Studio options we have upgraded the memory usage, we also have formatted the workstation and updated all the drivers from DELL website.T his is issue appears alsowithout devices and network cable connected to the workstation.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: The emulator works independent of Android studio so you should better mention the emulator version than the Android a studio version. Do you use HAXM or HyperV Emulation system? See SDK which package is installed and system info if your Windows is running with HyperV enabled.

Comment: Hello @Robert, we have Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator HAXM version 7.6.5 , Hyper-V feature is not enabled on the PC. Thank you